# Chart.js not being displayed inside Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, chart.js

I am trying to display a chart with Chart.js inside a Jquery dialog. If I display the chart on a regular page it show without any problem.

This is the Smarty template I am using to try to display the chart (it's being included inside the dialog):

```
<div class="recentstats">
    {translate id=1431}
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <div class="chartLegend"></div>
</div>
<script src="{$scriptbase}Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

        var data = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",     "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                }
            ]
        };

        var options = {

                //animation: false,
                //scaleoverride: true,
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                animationSteps: 1,
                scaleShowGridLines: true,
                scaleShowLabels: true,
                pointHitDetectionRadius: 5,
                pointDotRadius: 3,
                pointDotStrokeWidth: 0,
                scaleFontColor: "#2b2b2b",
                tooltipFillColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
                tooltipFontColor: "#2b2b2b",
                tooltipFontSize: 12,
                multiTooltipKeyBackground: "transparent",
                tooltipStrokeColor: "rgba(43,43,43,0.7)",
                tooltipTitleFontColor: "#2b2b2b",
                multiTooltipTemplate: {literal}'<% if (datasetLabel) {%><%= datasetLabel %>: <%= value %> <%if ( optional.ranking ) {%> -  {/literal}{translate id=480}{literal}: <%= optional.ranking %> <%} }%>',{/literal}
                legendTemplate: {literal}"<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){ if (datasets[i].label) {%><li><span class=\"chartLegendColor\" style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].pointColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><span class=\"chartLegendLabel\"><%=datasets[i].label%></span><%}%></li><%} }%></ul>"{/literal}

        };

        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
        $(".chartLegend").html(myLineChart.generateLegend());
    });
</script>
```

Here I am opening the dialog:

```
<script>    
        var buttons = {
            Join: {
                text: '{translate id=1434}',
                click: function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    showLoadingScreen();
                    showMiniSearchLoadingScreen();
                    performAction({
                        action: "addPlayer",
                        playerid: {$playerdetails.player_id},
                        starting: 1,
                        leagueid: memberleagueid
                    });
                    // close dialog after adding player
                    $( this ).dialog( "destroy" );
                }
            }
        }

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 855,
        height: 650,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: 'no-close fixed-dialog player-profile-dialog',

        buttons: buttons,


    }).attr('id', 'dialog');

    function newPopup(url) {
        popupWindow = window.open(
                   url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=960,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
    }

</script>
```

Now, when I inspect the element with Firebug, the canvas has a width and height of 0, which explains why the chart can't be drawn. But I don't understand why the width and height are set to 0.

I am also using Bootstrap tabs inside the dialog, but even without the tabs, the chart is not being displayed.

Anybody know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself. Strangely enough, what made it work was moving the code that instantiates the chart object to the same Smarty template where I am calling the dialog. In that case, the canvas does have a size, and the chart is drawn correctly. 
It is also displayed correctly inside the Bootstrap tab, and I can switch between tabs and the chart still works.

(In my case, the chart is being displayed in the first tab, which is set to active. If the chart is in another tab that's not active yet, I need to use "$('#tab1').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e)" instead of "$(document).ready(function()")

So the code now looks like this:

```
<script>

    var buttons = {

            Join: {

                text: '{translate id=1434}',

                click: function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();



                    showLoadingScreen();

                    showMiniSearchLoadingScreen();

                    performAction({

                        action: "addPlayer",

                        playerid: {$playerdetails.player_id},

                        starting: 1,

                        leagueid: memberleagueid

                    });

                    // close dialog after adding player

                    $( this ).dialog( "destroy" );

                }

            }

        }



    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({

        resizable: false,
        width: 855,
        height: 650,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: 'no-close fixed-dialog player-profile-dialog',         

        buttons: buttons,   

    }).attr('id', 'dialog');

    function newPopup(url) {

        popupWindow = window.open(
            url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=960,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')

    }



    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

        var data = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],

            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]

                }
            ]
        };    

        var options = {                 

                //animation: false,
                //scaleoverride: true,
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                bezierCurve: false,
                animationSteps: 1,
                scaleShowGridLines: true,
                scaleShowLabels: true,
                pointHitDetectionRadius: 5,
                pointDotRadius: 3,
                pointDotStrokeWidth: 0,
                scaleFontColor: "#2b2b2b",
                tooltipFillColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
                tooltipFontColor: "#2b2b2b",
                tooltipFontSize: 12,
                multiTooltipKeyBackground: "transparent",
                tooltipStrokeColor: "rgba(43,43,43,0.7)",
                tooltipTitleFontColor: "#2b2b2b",
                multiTooltipTemplate: {literal}'<% if (datasetLabel) {%><%= datasetLabel %>: <%= value %> <%if ( optional.ranking ) {%> -  {/literal}{translate id=480}{literal}: <%= optional.ranking %> <%} }%>',{/literal}
                legendTemplate: {literal}"<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){ if (datasets[i].label) {%><li><span class=\"chartLegendColor\" style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].pointColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><span class=\"chartLegendLabel\"><%=datasets[i].label%></span><%}%></li><%} }%></ul>"{/literal}

    };

    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
});
```